# Remove string and add sequential number to file headers using awk or sed

Tags: regex, awk, sed, bioinformatics

I have following `input`:

```
>Thimo_0001|ID:40710520| hypothetical protein [Thioflavicoccus mobilis 8321]
LIAPTMILRIRLTEFCPMRTEGFEE
TGIGPLDSRMPRYDDVVHHREIIT
YPPEALSNDPFDPTSIDGSPSAFF*
>ThimoAM_0002|ID:40707134| protein of unknown function [Thioflavicoccus mobilis 8321]
VRKAERDSPCKRRGADRSFP
KSARLISSKAFRDVFAESITNSDPFFVVR
ARPNLAETARLGIAVSKKCARRSVDRSRIKRII
RESFRWVRNDLPVMDYVVIARHAAVKRTNPRLFESLRSHWTKFSEPDA*
>Thimo_0002|ID:40710524| ribonuclease P protein component [Thioflavicoccus mobilis 8321]
MILLIRLRSTDRRAHFFDTAIPNLAVSARLGRAR
TTKNGSEFVMDSAKTSRNAFEEISLADFGKERSAP
RRLQGESLSAFRTTRGQDEPATFRCPTRPKPMCMRAL*
```

And I would like to

1. remove the linebreaks in lines after the header starting with `>`
2. remove the asterisk
3. change the fasta header

I could do `1.` and `2.`

```
awk '!/^>/ { printf "%s", $0; n = "\n" } /^>/ { print n $0; n = "" } END { printf "%s", n }' 
sed "s/\*//g"
```

and I can also add a sequential number to the end of the header line:

```
awk '/^>/{$0=$0"_"(++i)}1'
```

but I am failing at the last step with the replacing/removing and adding a sequential number:

desired `output`

```
>TM0001|hypothetical_protein  
LIAPTMILRIRLTEFCPMRTEGFEETGIGPLDSRMPRYDDVVHHREIITYPPEALSNDPFDPTSIDGSPSAFF
>TM0002|protein_of_unknown_function  
VRKAERDSPCKRRGADRSFPKSARLISSKAFRDVFAESITNSDPFFVVRARPNLAETARLGIAVSKKCARRSVDRSRIKRIIRESFRWVRNDLPVMDYVVIARHAAVKRTNPRLFESLRSHWTKFSEPDA
>TM0003|ribonuclease_P_protein_component  
MILLIRLRSTDRRAHFFDTAIPNLAVSARLGRARTTKNGSEFVMDSAKTSRNAFEEISLADFGKERSAPRRLQGESLSAFRTTRGQDEPATFRCPTRPKPMCMRAL
```

Answer (score 1):

According to your "desired" output - ***gawk*** solution:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ RS=">"; FS="[|\\]\\[]" }!$0{ next }
     { gsub(/^ */,"",$3); gsub(/[*[:space:]]/,"",$5); printf(">TM%04d|%s\n%s\n",++c,$3,$5) 
}' yourfile
```

The output:

```
>TM0001|hypothetical protein 
LIAPTMILRIRLTEFCPMRTEGFEETGIGPLDSRMPRYDDVVHHREIITYPPEALSNDPFDPTSIDGSPSAFF
>TM0002|protein of unknown function 
VRKAERDSPCKRRGADRSFPKSARLISSKAFRDVFAESITNSDPFFVVRARPNLAETARLGIAVSKKCARRSVDRSRIKRIIRESFRWVRNDLPVMDYVVIARHAAVKRTNPRLFESLRSHWTKFSEPDA
>TM0003|ribonuclease P protein component 
MILLIRLRSTDRRAHFFDTAIPNLAVSARLGRARTTKNGSEFVMDSAKTSRNAFEEISLADFGKERSAPRRLQGESLSAFRTTRGQDEPATFRCPTRPKPMCMRAL
```

---

Details:

- `RS=">"` - considering `>` as record separator
- `FS="[|\\]\\[]"` - field separator, any of characters `|[]`
- `!$0{ next }` - skip empty records
- `gsub(/^ */,"",$3)` - remove leading spaces in the 3rd field
- `gsub(/[*[:space:]]/,"",$5)` - replace/remove asterisk `*` and whitespace characters within the 5th field